# Using batch to robocopy to computer addresses stored in a txt file

Tags: batch-file

So basically I wanted to write a batch so I could type a bunch of computer names into a text file, have the batch pull the names and use them as variables to set the destination for a robocopy.

So something like:

```
 for (i = line of file.txt) 
 if i != null  then
 var(i) = dest
 robocopy src dest /e
```

so far I've <s>plagiarized</s> paraphrased some stuff and I've got the following

```
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (c:\Users\test_list1.txt) 
   do set var=%%a&call :process

   if [%%a] == [] do (
   Set src=(c:\folder\source.txt)
   Set dest=%%a
   robocopy %src% %dest% /e

   :process
   echo var=%var%
   goto :eof
```

I used to be reasonably awful at Java, but I'm kind of lost with scripting this.

Not that it's awfully relevant, but for information's sake. I'm copying minecraftedu to some 30+ machines in a school. I'd rather use another method, but the nature of the setup here means I'm limited to manually going machine to machine with a flash drive or using xcopy/robo.

Comment: You need to reverse the `if` like `if not` (I guess you do not want to copy anything if the destination is nothing); the closing `)` is missing for the `if` block; then remove the `()` around the `src` value...

Answer (score 0):

Set "src=c:\folder\source.txt"
   for /f "delims=" %%a in (c:\Users\test_list1.txt) do echo %%a&xcopy "%src%" "%%a\" /s /e

should be equivalent.

You don't say why or whether you are using the `var` array you are establishing in your pseudocode, so I dropped it.

The quotes in the `set` statement ensure that stray terminal spaces are not included in the value assigned. Those in the `xcopy` are to combine the strings into two identifiable tokens in case one or the other contains a separator like space.

Your problems are:

the `do` keyword and its following `(` must be on the same physical line as the `for` (there are circumstances where this is not so, but the rules and regulations are too complex for a simple explanation)

The `%%a` in the `if` statement is out-of-scope.

`%%a` will never be *nothing* so testing it is superfluous in any case.

There is no `do` in an `if` statement. Your code would attempt to find an executable, and execute `do (` where `(` is simply a character.

That `(`, even if the `do` was removed is unterminated.

There seems no reason to repeatedly set `src` to the same value, and the parentheses there are significant and part of the value assigned.

If the lines following the unterminated `(` up to the `:label` are expected to be a code-block, then the values assigned within the code block are inaccessible without `delayedexpansion`.

Having executed the mainline, batch assigns no special meaning to a label. It's simply a marker - it does not signify the end of a "procedure". You'd need to execute a `goto :eof` just before the label to skip the procedure code, else the procedure code will be executed by "fall-through"